# Nginx ingress not exposing port on machine

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a freshly installed cluster running kubernetes 1.22 on Ubuntu 20.04 with Nginx installed. I can't get Nginx be exposed on the host machine on Port 80/443. If I curl the virtual host from within the Nginx pod, I can reach the service.

```
Name:         ingress-nginx-controller-76dcf4d6c8-szs8s
Namespace:    ingress-nginx
Priority:     0
Node:         kub-worker-1/192.168.2.86
Start Time:   Thu, 19 Aug 2021 15:02:02 +0000
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
              app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
              pod-template-hash=76dcf4d6c8
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.0.0.156
IPs:
  IP:           10.0.0.156
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/ingress-nginx-controller-76dcf4d6c8
Containers:
  controller:
    Container ID:  docker://5ba153e69ddc8744002605c47a58fc748d15e913b2becd8e6fe425de52fff5f7
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.0.0-beta.3@sha256:44a7a06b71187a4529b0a9edee5cc22bdf71b414470eff696c3869ea8d90a695
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller@sha256:44a7a06b71187a4529b0a9edee5cc22bdf71b414470eff696c3869ea8d90a695
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP, 8443/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
      --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
      --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
      --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
      --validating-webhook=:8443
      --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
      --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 19 Aug 2021 15:02:03 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   90Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:  http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:       ingress-nginx-controller-76dcf4d6c8-szs8s (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  ingress-nginx (v1:metadata.namespace)
      LD_PRELOAD:     /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
    Mounts:
      /usr/local/certificates/ from webhook-cert (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-mql58 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  webhook-cert:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  ingress-nginx-admission
    Optional:    false
  kube-api-access-mql58:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

Ufw enabled with:

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 6443                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 6783/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 6784/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] 6783/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 6] 2379/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 7] 2380/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 8] 8472/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 9] 4240/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[10] 8472/udp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[11] 4240/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
[12] 4244/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[13] 4245/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[14] 6060/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[15] 6061/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[16] 6062/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[17] 6942/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[18] 9090/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[19] 9876/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[20] 9890/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[21] 9891/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[22] 9892/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[23] 9893/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[24] 51871/udp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[25] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[26] 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[27] 8080/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[28] 12000/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[29] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[30] 6443 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[31] 6783/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[32] 6784/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[33] 6783/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[34] 2379/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[35] 2380/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[36] 8472/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[37] 4240/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[38] 8472/udp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[39] 4240/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              (out)
[40] 4244/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[41] 4245/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[42] 6060/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[43] 6061/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[44] 6062/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[45] 6942/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[46] 9090/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[47] 9876/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[48] 9890/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[49] 9891/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[50] 9892/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[51] 9893/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[52] 51871/udp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[53] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[54] 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[55] 12000/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Exposed ports:

```
systemd-r    899 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4   21166      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       18827            root    3u  IPv4   52153      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       18827            root    4u  IPv6   52155      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
container  20083            root   13u  IPv4   60776      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:37531 (LISTEN)
kube-cont  34531            root    7u  IPv4  107006      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:10257 (LISTEN)
etcd       34589            root    7u  IPv4  106830      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.52:2380 (LISTEN)
etcd       34589            root    8u  IPv4  106834      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:2379 (LISTEN)
etcd       34589            root    9u  IPv4  106835      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.52:2379 (LISTEN)
etcd       34589            root   13u  IPv4  107720      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:2381 (LISTEN)
kube-sche  34603            root    7u  IPv4  107783      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:10259 (LISTEN)
kube-apis  34618            root    7u  IPv6  107757      0t0  TCP *:6443 (LISTEN)
kubelet    37098            root   13u  IPv4  114512      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:33915 (LISTEN)
kubelet    37098            root   31u  IPv6  114560      0t0  TCP *:10250 (LISTEN)
kubelet    37098            root   34u  IPv4  114566      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:10248 (LISTEN)
cilium-op 143227            root    7u  IPv4  563370      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9891 (LISTEN)
cilium-op 143227            root    8u  IPv4  563375      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9234 (LISTEN)
cilium-ag 158094            root    7u  IPv4  619482      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9890 (LISTEN)
cilium-ag 158094            root    8u  IPv6  663676      0t0  TCP *:30206 (LISTEN)
cilium-ag 158094            root   23u  IPv6  619998      0t0  TCP *:42707 (LISTEN)
cilium-ag 158094            root   47u  IPv4  623102      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9876 (LISTEN)
cilium-ag 158094            root   64u  IPv6  623295      0t0  TCP *:4244 (LISTEN)
cilium-ag 158094            root   67u  IPv6  623305      0t0  TCP *:4240 (LISTEN)
```

From within the nginx container

```
bash-5.1$ curl --header "Host: linkerd.internal.damn.li" localhost

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Linkerd</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Linkerd">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Linkerd">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/dist/img/favicon.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    
  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/index_bundle.js" async></script>
  

  </head>
  <body>
    
  <div class="main" id="main"
    data-release-version="stable-2.10.2"
    data-go-version="go1.16.2"
    data-controller-namespace="linkerd"
    data-uuid="0766d708-1cdd-4225-a4b5-c587b503c3e6"
    data-grafana="grafana.linkerd-viz.svc.cluster.local:3000"
    data-jaeger="">
    
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Update 2:

I have found these configuration lines in the helm chart. It was set to false and I have changed it to true. However, the ports are still not exposed.  I wonder if it will work at all, as I'm using Cilium as CNI.

```
  # Required for use with CNI based kubernetes installations (such as ones set up by kubeadm),
  # since CNI and hostport don't mix yet. Can be deprecated once https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23920
  # is merged
  hostNetwork: true
```

Update 3:

Helm values file: https://pastebin.com/njpBTu9q

Pod definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-22T12:04:29Z"
  generateName: ingress-nginx-controller-88758fc9-
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    pod-template-hash: 88758fc9
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-88758fc9-pl4kl
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: ingress-nginx-controller-88758fc9
    uid: 8d1441f7-92b0-497a-a0c7-e9685253ba5c
  resourceVersion: "545734"
  uid: abb6fb65-f06e-4cfa-b3b5-cd6de52e7fad
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - /nginx-ingress-controller
    - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
    - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
    - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
    - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
    - --validating-webhook=:8443
    - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
    - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
    env:
    - name: POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    - name: POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: LD_PRELOAD
      value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
    image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.0.0-beta.3@sha256:44a7a06b71187a4529b0a9edee5cc22bdf71b414470eff696c3869ea8d90a695
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command:
          - /wait-shutdown
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 5
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 10254
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    name: controller
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      hostPort: 80
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 443
      hostPort: 443
      name: https
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 8443
      hostPort: 8443
      name: webhook
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 10254
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 90Mi
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      capabilities:
        add:
        - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        drop:
        - ALL
      runAsUser: 101
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
      name: webhook-cert
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-dfft5
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  hostNetwork: true
  nodeName: kub-worker-1
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: ingress-nginx
  serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: webhook-cert
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
  - name: kube-api-access-dfft5
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-08-22T12:04:29Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-08-22T12:04:49Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-08-22T12:04:49Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-08-22T12:04:29Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://200bc5cd1cea0fda6967d28d27cbf199834c7857bc49fce6c314240f6c4821e0
    image: sha256:11d6381f7abc4250c143a97419d269adde01b2c51a874723357eead09c810dcb
    imageID: docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller@sha256:44a7a06b71187a4529b0a9edee5cc22bdf71b414470eff696c3869ea8d90a695
    lastState: {}
    name: controller
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2021-08-22T12:04:31Z"
  hostIP: 192.168.2.86
  phase: Running
  podIP: 192.168.2.86
  podIPs:
  - ip: 192.168.2.86
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: "2021-08-22T12:04:29Z"
```

Comment: Share your Pod YAML definition

Comment: I have added the missing piece of information.

Comment: How did you setup Kubernetes cluster - `kubeadm`, `microk8s` or something different?

Comment: I have used kubeadm  to install.

Comment: In which way are you trying to access it? What do you mean by "Nginx installed" - you installed [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/), not "normal" nginx app. These are two different things.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I had to install the beta but in the meanwhile the official version was released.

Answer (score 0):

Checking your description, we can see:

```
 Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
```

This means your container ports are not exposed on your host.

Edit your deployment or statefulset. Add hostNetwork: true

```
spec:
  containers:
  - [...]
  hostNetwork: true
```

If your cluster uses PodSecurityPolicies, you may need to grant your controller with permissions starting containers without network isolation.

Comment: I have added a little bit more information in the original post. In fact the hostNetwork attribute was set to false. However, the Helm values.yaml mentions that while using a CNI hostNetwork can not be set to true. I wonder how it will work then. The ports are still not exposed after setting hostNetwork to true.